# Angularjs intercepting routes of the backbone app

Tags: angularjs, backbone.js, routes, angular-ui-router

We are slowly transitioning to AngularJS from Backbone feature by feature. The problem is that angularjs intercepts all the route changes and doesn't let backbone listen to route changes.

Is there a way to let angular ignore the routes that it has not been programmed to take an action on ?

Answer (score 2):

You can add **target="_self"** for all the backbone links, then angular would not route those links. We had the same problem and adding this fixed the problem. Hope this helps..

```
<a href="/test" target="_self">Test</a>
```